# conditional html rules for IE

Tags: html, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use conditional rules for IE and other browsers for a redirect. The problem is that it only works in IE and in all the other remains in the redirect page. 
This is the code of the page:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Benessere Globale</TITLE>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!--[if lt IE9]>
    <p class="chromeframe">Stai usando una versione di Internet Explorer <strong>obsoleta</strong>. Per una migliore visualizzazione di questo sito <a href="http://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/internet-explorer-9-details.aspx">aggiorna il tuo browser alla versione IE9 o IE10</a> o <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">attiva Google Chrome Frame</a>.<br><br>
    <span>Per visualizzare comunque il sito <a href="/beta/shtml/home.shtml" >clicca qu&igrave;</a></span>
    </p>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.benessereglobale.net/beta/shtml/home.shtml">
<![endif]-->


</HEAD>
<BODY>
<p>Redirect in corso...</p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

thanks

Comment: The above condition works only for IE, as I know. Other browsers ignore this.

Comment: Remove second part and make only `[if lt IE9]`. because IE only can read condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only IE can read conditional comments, not other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Only IE can read the conditional comments.

But the new version (IE10 or later) can't read the conditional comments.